# GLFW, Vulkan && C++ window doesn't show up on my Hyprland/Wayland window manager

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan, wayland

I'm new to graphics programming and new to glfw and I tried to setup my glfw project from vulkan-tutorial.com but the window doesn't show up and the console output shows success messages.

Here is the source code of main.cpp file

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    if(!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "Init failed!\n";

        return -1;
    }

     std::cout << "Init success!\n";

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Vulkan window", nullptr, nullptr);

    if (window == NULL) {
         std::cout << "GLFW window creation failed\n";
         
         return -1;
     }

     std::cout << "GLFW window created!\n";

    uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);

    std::cout << extensionCount << " extensions supported\n";

    glm::mat4 matrix;
    glm::vec4 vec;
    auto test = matrix * vec;

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile command :

```
g++ -o app main.cpp -lglfw -ldl -lvulkan
```

Output of my program : ./app

```
Init Success!
GLFW window created!
22 extensions supported
```

But I don't see any window. I found a similar issue on https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1398 but as I'm a beginner I didn't know what to do so and this was my last resort so could anyone please help?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I myself have no experience with Wayland or Vulkan but based on the comments in the provided link, it seems that you have to render onto a surface first. (_"This is by design. A Wayland window is not shown until a buffer is commited."_ - **and** - _"GLFW can’t render to your buffer by itself on window creation because it would require doing the entire OpenGL or Vulkan initialisation dance before calling a clear function, which the user of the library may not even want. If you want to start with a black window, you should render that yourself first thing once you have your VkSurfaceKHR."_).

Comment: Erdal Küçük, Thanks for the help I tried using sdl and had the same problem in wayland but as you said, a buffer should be commited for a window to show up in wayland so I'll try to follow tutorials even if my window doesn't show up and then hopefully at one point where a cube or triangle renders my window shows up!